# Where can I get a lot of second key animations?

Tags: resources

I am working on a project with neural networks and artificial intelligence. I want to train a neural network to draw simple anime. For technical reasons, I need to train such a model by feeding it lots of data. To be exact, I need second keys for anime in order to train the model.

I need a lot, hundreds of thousands, I know they exist somewhere, but I have no idea how I can get them.

Is there a place where I can freely find a lot of second keys? Maybe there is a place I can buy second key drawings?

Comment: I don't understand why do you believe there is lots of internal material like key animations. 
I think you can make such data yourself. Maybe take normal animation sequence and "extract" a frame every ~1-3 seconds. With other frames being in-betweens your AI will train to fill in.

Comment: I meant that such materials surely exist somewhere in archives of the studios. I'm not an animator, so I don't know the details of what happens to the raw materials after the anime release.

Comment: And yes, I can create dataset, but that would be unrealistic, since the keys have different colored lines representing shadows and lights, as well as some comments and different layers, and as far as I know, different number of frames needed for different scenes. The anime then goes through a coloring and post-production phase. Therefore, I cannot create a realistic keys from the anime. Maybe something close, but getting keyframes will still be much better.